# Display Grand Total only when a column have value greater than 0

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have DEALER   MAP  Quantity columns in Google Sheets
On the MAP column I am having my Grand total which is the SUM of my MAP column.
The Quantity column is having 0s which means there is no Product selected.

I want to show the Grand Total as 0 under MAP but Not 0 when any number more than 0 is added into Quantity.

The 10% is the row for finding TAX.The fomulas are here
for TAX

```
=(D3*E3+D5*E5+D6*E6+D7*E7+D8*E8+D9*E9+D10*E10+D11*E11+D12*E12+D13*E13+D14*E14+D15*E15)*D20
```

For The Grand Total

```
=SUM(D3:D15,E20)
```

[image: This is the picture of my columns]

Comment: You are on excel or google sheet? Two are different product. If excel then mention your excel version.

Comment: I am on google sheets.

Comment: You may try `SUMIFS()` function.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 2):

you can use IF like:

```
=IF(SUM(D3:D15, E20)=0,, SUM(D3:D15, E20))
```

or if you are not fan of repeating formula twice you can do:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(D3:D15, E20))
```

---

### update:

```
=SUM(FILTER(IFERROR(D3:D20*E3:E20), E3:E20<>0),E29)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not showing 0 sum even if all the numbers in quantity are 0's.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cxde4qZRPWhT0PZH9eQZBa6y8CCyaOFR/edit#gid=1940500609 here is an example of the file.

Comment: @Davidwatson is this what you are after? https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9THS.png

Comment: @Davidwatson or this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8VgJ.png